# journalctl vacuum not working

Tags: fedora, systemd, journal, vacuum

I recently started using Fedora 25 and I'm trying to clear the journal logs manually but it's not working. For example:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 24.0M on disk.
```

I try to clear with:

```
$ journalctl --vacuum-size=1M
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals on disk.
```

It's not freeing anything. Any ideas? The system is freshly installed and I haven't touched the `journald.conf` yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the man page of `journalct`.

> Note that running --vacuum-size= has only indirect effect on the output shown by --disk-usage as the latter includes active journal files, while the former only operates on archived journal files.

So it seems as you only have active journal files which are not cleared by `--vacuum-size`.

Comment: After several weeks of logging, I checked the journal size and it was 165MB, then I ran `journalctl --vacuum-size=1M` and indeed it deleted two archived journals (72+8MB). The journal size is now 88MB.
`Vacuuming done, freed 80.0M of archived journals on disk.`